# Visual Studio Code C/C++ extension's "Improved Member Function Completion" not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, extension

In https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/vs-code-cpp-extension-january-2019-update/ I see that the c/c++ vscode extension has a feature:

> With improved member function completion, the selected completion is
>   committed after a parenthesis “(“ is entered.

But it's not working on my computer. I have the latest vscode and c/c++ extension, and I already turned on "Editor: Accept Suggestion On Commit Character". Is there any other options that I missed? Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked with the devs of this extension about this issue?

Comment: @music2myear Thanks a lot, I posted an issue, they said this feature was removed.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/4513), the feature is already removed.